# JS Promise and event loop execution

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm new in javascript, coming from firmware / embedded system / RTOS background. I don't understand the concept of the context switching for JS promise.

For this script:

```
setTimeout(() => { console.log("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

I can understand that the callback is registered in event loop task, the script continues until finish and exit. The the event loop run and executes any task / callback that is due.

For this script:

```
var pr = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve() }, 3000);
});
pr().then(() => { 
    console.log("Hello"); 
});
```

Does it mean that the script will run `pr()`, exit the script, run the event loop. Once event loop executes the callback (calling `resolve()`), the JS will switch context to the script again, and run anything inside `then()` clause ?

Or the script will run until finish, but the `then()` clause is registered as callback in event queue when `resolve()` is called. Then the event queue will execute the `then()` clause ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You are close. Promises have a special place in the event queue in the form of microtasks. This should clarify everything: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Comment: In your example, `pr` is already a promise so you would do `pr.then()`, not `pr().then()`.  `pr` is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

The second, rather. [Promises are just an abstraction atop callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572), there's no magic going on here.

The script runs until completion, creating the promise and calling `setTimeout` (which installs its callback on the timer) and calling `then` (which installs its callback on the promise). Then the event loop will advance and run timeout callback, which calls `resolve` which in turn leads to the promise callback to be executed.